# Recreate various Non-Parametric ANCOVA analyses in R

Tags: r, covariance, rank, anova

I am looking to recreate various analyses in R that can compute several types of Non-Parametric ANCOVA.

Let's use the `mtcars` data from the `datasets` package in R for example purposes. Let's say I wanted to predict `MPG` from `Transmission` while controlling for `Cylinders`. I would conduct a normal ANCOVA in R with the following code:

```
summary(aov(mpg ~ cyl + am, mtcars))
```

That part is easy. Here is where things get a bit tricky for me (given that I am not statistics savvy). I have been reading several articles that talk about different approaches to Non-Parametric ANCOVA. For example, [on page 334 of this article](https://music.fsu.edu/sites/g/files/imported/storage/original/application/bee1849ced1d1e70dabac499500f7a09.pdf) published by Lawson (1983) describes three different approaches of Non-Parametric ANCOVA:

- Parametric ANCOVA on Ranks
- [Quade's Non-Parametric ANCOVA](http://imaging.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/statswiki/FAQ/Quade)
- [Puri and Sen's Non-Parametric ANCOVA](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177697729)

I think I am on the right track recreating the first two with the following code:

```
summary(aov(rank(mpg) ~ rank(cyl) + am, mtcars)) ## Ranks
summary(aov(lm(rank(mpg) ~ rank(cyl), mtcars)$residuals ~ am, mtcars)) ## Quade
```

However, I am at a loss when it comes to recreating the Puri and Sen's Non-Parametric ANCOVA. I did come across [this article](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2016/RJ-2016-027/RJ-2016-027.pdf). On page 374 where the paragraph talks about Quade's work, the author mentions a procedure that is slightly different from Quade's version of ANCOVA. I wonder if this is the Puri and Sen approach or something different? I recreated what was described below. It appears to be a modified version of the above Quade code.

```
summary(lm(rank(mpg) ~ rank(cyl) + am, mtcars)) ## Puri and Sen?
```

Just to summarize, I am exploring different ways to run a Non-Parametric ANCOVA, and I would like to recreate both Quade's and Puri and Sen's procedures in R. If there are any other methods, I would also be interested in exploring those.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day of reading about the procedures, I have about 2/3 of an answer. According to Chapter 5 of Bonate's (2000) text, Quade's Non-Parametric ANCOVA is calculated as follows:

```
# Transform the CYL and MPG to Ranks
mtcars$cylRank <- rank(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$mpgRank <- rank(mtcars$mpg)

# Convert to Ranks to Deviation Scores
mtcars$cylDev <- mtcars$cylRank - mean(mtcars$cylRank )
mtcars$mpgDev <- mtcars$mpgRank - mean(mtcars$mpgRank )

# Spearman Correlation
cor.1 <- with(mtcars, cor(mpgRank , cylRank , method="spearman"))

# Deviation Rank of MPG is Predicted from the Deviation Rank of CYL
mtcars$est.mpg <- mtcars$cylDev * cor.1

# Predicted Deviation Rank of MPG is Subtracted from the Observed Deviation Rank of CYL
mtcars$mpg.resid <- mtcars$est.mpg - mtcars$mpgDev

# ANOVA on the Residual Deviation Rank Scores
summary(aov(mpg.resid ~ am, mtcars))
```

I was mistaken above where I thought the Puri and Sen procedure was analyzed on just ranks. That analysis in known as a Parametric ANCOVA on the Ranks. It is run as follows:

```
Anova(aov(rank(mpg) ~ rank(cyl) + am, mtcars), type="III)
```

The only information I have on the Puri and Sen test statistic (`Ln`) is that it tests the hypothesis of no treatment effect and is distributed as a chi-square random variable. Quade's method is merely a special case of the Puri and Sen procedure (but with a different distribution).

I will keep this question open until a solution on how to calculate the Puri and Sen test statistic in R is presented.